# How to make a periphery configuration within multiple targets

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, configuration

I'm using Periphery for iOS project and I have the project target and widgets target, how can I make the Periphery configuration to be able to make the scan and to make sure the code in the main target is actually used in the widgets?